# What is resource-ref in web.xml used for?

Tags: java, web.xml, resource-ref

I'm just wondering when/why you would define a `<resource-ref>` element in your `web.xml` file?

I would have thought that it would be defined in your web/app server using JNDI and then look up the JNDI reference in your Java code?

The resource-ref definition seems a bit redundant to me and I can't think of when it might be useful. Example:

```xml
<resource-ref>
  <description>Primary database</description>
  <res-ref-name>jdbc/primaryDB</res-ref-name>
  <res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
  <res-auth>CONTAINER</res-auth>
</resource-ref>
```

Answer (score 163, accepted):

You can always refer to resources in your application directly by their JNDI name as configured in the container, but if you do so, essentially you are wiring the container-specific name into your code. This has some disadvantages, for example, if you'll ever want to change the name later for some reason, you'll need to update all the references in all your applications, and then rebuild and redeploy them.

`<resource-ref>` introduces another layer of indirection: you specify the name you want to use in the *web.xml*, and, depending on the container, provide a binding in a *container-specific* configuration file.

So **here's what happens**: let's say you want to lookup the `java:comp/env/jdbc/primaryDB` name. The container finds that *web.xml* has a `<resource-ref>` element for `jdbc/primaryDB`, so it will look into the container-specific configuration, that contains something similar to the following:

```xml
<resource-ref>
  <res-ref-name>jdbc/primaryDB</res-ref-name>
  <jndi-name>jdbc/PrimaryDBInTheContainer</jndi-name>
</resource-ref>
```

Finally, it returns the object registered under the name of `jdbc/PrimaryDBInTheContainer`.

**The idea** is that specifying resources in the *web.xml* has the advantage of separating the **developer** role from the **deployer** role. In other words, as a developer, you don't have to know what your required resources are actually called in production, and as the guy deploying the application, you will have a nice list of names to map to real resources.

Comment: IMHO, it goes beyond separating the roles. The idea is that you can't assume that a jndi name is available on a server so you need a way to map the name used in your application on the "real" JNDI name chosen by the deployer.

Comment: This must be elementary, since I can't find it with Google, but if I want to look up "java:comp/env/jdbc/primaryDB", then why is the res-ref-name "jdbc/primaryDB"?

Comment: For what I know, the "jndi-name" element is NOT part of standard web.xml, but rather of specific vendors deployment descriptors.

Comment: `jndi-name` is part of jboss-web.xml but not web.xml. But +1 For Good explaination. [Example](https://docs.jboss.org/jbossas/docs/Server_Configuration_Guide/4/html/ENC_Usage_Conventions-Resource_Manager_Connection_Factory_References_with_jboss.xml_and_jboss_web.xml.html#Resource_Manager_Connection_Factory_References_with_jboss.xml_and_jboss_web.xml-A_sample_jboss_web.xml_resource_ref_descriptor_fragment)

Comment: @RaviParekh, he has mentioned "container-specific configuration", it might be jboss-web.xml or weblogic.xml or any other vendor specific deployment descriptor file

Comment: Can we relate this to tomcat ? I mean datasource defined in context.xml in tomcat and resource-ref in web.xml

Comment: If some containers use `jndi-name` to map the indirection  but this is not standard, what is the standard ? [Tomcat seems to require both names match](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/jndi-resources-howto.html#Generic_JavaBean_Resources:~:text=To%20configure%20Tomcat's%20resource%20factory%2C%20add%20an%20element%20like%20this%20to%20the%20%3CContext%3E%20element%20for%20this,in%20the%20web%20application%20deployment%20descriptor) which brings us back to the original question: what's the point?

Comment: As updating the resource JNDI name happens once in a blue moon, is this overhead worth it? I'd just update the resource name in all the web apps and redeploy them.

Answer (score 0):

An old question, but I have a nice example of where this is useful. I've got two WAR files based on a common framework, and which need to be deployed into the same application server... they require different data sources, but because of the common framework, they use the same JNDI to look it up. It's further complicated by the fact that they're deployed on WebLogic for production and Tomcat for testing, so portability of the container-specific names is a factor.

Using `<resource-ref>` makes it simple... the framework supplies a common `web.xml` which looks for a specific name of `jdbc/myDataSource`, and external to the application itself, both WebLogic and Tomcat can be configured to serve a suitable data source under that alias. And because the alias is application specific, multiple applications in the same server can request the same JNDI name, and get different data sources as required.