# Spring Error: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException

Tags: spring, web-applications, websphere, jndi

I have a web application which I am exporting as EAR and trying to deploy on Websphere 6.1 application server.

The deployment goes fine. Even, the index page loads fine which is a login screen.

However, on entering credentials and hitting enter, the next page does not load and HTTP 500 Internal Server Error is thrown.

The next page which gets loaded is a JSP having a country drop down, whose values gets fetched from database via hibernate.

I have Datasource created in Websphere with all details and even test connection succeeds.

However, I get the below error on checking the server System.out logs:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'ds': 
Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: 
Context: uschwasvmdev04Cell01/clusters/URMDUS, name: jdbc/mydbXA: First component in name 
mydbXA not found. [Root exception is org.omg.CosNaming.NamingContextPackage.NotFound: 
IDL:omg.org/CosNaming/NamingContext/NotFound:1.0]
```

The description of NameNotFoundException says:

"This exception is thrown when a component of the name cannot be resolved because it is not bound. "

JNDI Lookup in my services.xml also seems fine:

```
<jee:jndi-lookup id="ds" jndi-name="jdbc/mydbXA" resource-ref="true" />
```

What am I missing here ?

Thanks for reading!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using `resource-ref="true"`. Have you created the according [resource-reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2887967/what-is-resource-ref-in-web-xml-used-for) in your web.xml and did you [map the DataSource to the application](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v8r0/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.websphere.nd.multiplatform.doc%2Finfo%2Fae%2Fae%2Fudat_maprrr.html&resultof=%22map%22%20%22resource%22%20%22resourc%22%20%22references%22%20%22refer%22)?

If you set it to `false` you can do a global lookup. Otherwise you have to configure it.

Answer (score 0):

It's funny, but I've done the opposite: I created the resource-reference but I forget to tell Spring to use it.

Just in case, in the namespace it's done as you can see above: `resource-ref="true"`

If you're configuring your beans manually:

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
      <property name="jndiName" value="jdbc/database" /> 
      <property name="resourceRef" value="true" /><!-- It's false by default -->
</bean>
```