# Resource Definitions in context file for JNDI lookup

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jndi, web.xml, tomcat5.5

I have a query related to the contents of  element in context.xml file for Jndi look up and  the `resource-ref` element in web.xml . The [Tomcat 5.5 reference](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-5.5-doc/config/context.html#Resource%20Definitions) gives an overview of the `Resource` element.

1. As per the reference above , the valid attributes for `Resource` element  are `auth`,`description`,`name`,`scope`,`type` but we do include `driverClassName` , `url`, `username`, `password` etc and a same is in the sample in the [Tomcat docs](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-5.5-doc/jndi-resources-howto.html#JDBC_Data_Sources). So is the explanation in the former link wrong?
2. The reference states that the inclusion of the `<Resource>` element in `context.xml` file is equivalent to the `resource-ref` element in `web.xml` . If so , can we give the `driverClassName` , `url`, `username`, `password` and the remaining attributes in `web.xml` and give the `context.xml` file a miss ? I don't think we can . So why is the reference so confusing?

Answer (score 1):

1. Yes, it looks like the first reference is not comprehensive on all the attributes of the Resource element, the second one is much more comprehensive.
2. It is stated a little wrongly - instead of saying that the resource is equivalent to the resource-ref element in web.xml it should have said that the resource-ref in web.xml maps to the resource element in context.xml. It is a way to provide a local reference with its own name for the resource within a web application, and then during deployment time to map this internal resource name to a real container specific jndi resource - [What is resource-ref in web.xml used for?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2887967/what-is-resource-ref-in-web-xml-used-for)

Comment: Thanks @Biju - I'll give this question some more time . Your answer was helpful .