# comp/env/pool not found in context "java:"?

Tags: java, websphere, jndi, pool

I have a web application trying to access a JNDI declared in WebSphere Application Server.
The JNDI is declared under `Object pool managers`. However, I'm receiving an error when I access the pool. The error says that `comp/env/pool is not found in context "java:"`.

My code is written as follows:

```
InitialContext initialContext = new InitialContext();
ObjectPoolManager opm = (ObjectPoolManager)initialContext.lookup("java:comp/env/pool");
```

Accessing the pool via the code below works:

```
ObjectPoolManager opm = (ObjectPoolManager)initialContext.lookup("pool");
```

I'm confused because according to what I've found on the internet, `java:comp/env/` is a default prefix for JNDI. So why does it cause an error in my case?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

you can only use java:comp/env if you have declared a reference to the Object Pool in your web.xml under the resource-ref section.

See [What is resource-ref in web.xml used for?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2887967/what-is-resource-ref-in-web-xml-used-for) for further explanation.