# <res-ref-name> and <jndi-name> in web.xml

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jboss, web.xml

This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2887967/what-is-resource-ref-in-web-xml-used-for) is very helpful but I am still confused about following question

`<res-ref-name>` holds the jndi name definition in the `server(container)`

`<jndi-name>` holds the jndi alias which is prevalent within current application

is it correct?

but exactly when is it necessary to put `java:comp/env` in the `server's jndi definition` or in `<res-ref-name>`?