# Setting Spring @Profile from JNDI for SpringBoot

Tags: spring, tomcat, spring-boot, jndi

I'm deploying my SpringBoot Application to a Tomcat 8.5 container.
Similar as described here: http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-traditional-deployment.html I modified my SpringBootApplication, so it's deployable as war.

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder builder) {
        return builder.sources(Application.class);
    }
}
```

Similiar to this question [Activating Spring @Profile Using JNDI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19234686/activating-spring-profile-using-jndi) I wan't the application to select the active Profile using an JNDI entry.

I added an `EnvironmentApplicationContextInitializer` identical to the one shown in the accepted answer.

However: I do not use any `web.xml`. So the profile is not being picked up and used.

How do I make the SpringBootApplication using the `EnvironmentApplicationContextInitializer`?

Comment: You don't need it... Just register `SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE` as a JNDI entry (or `spring.profiles.active`) and it will be read. You don't need anything else.

Comment: Thanks, but (similar to the question linked) I have to reuse a already present JNDI-entry and mapping this entry is not an option either.
So I'd like to know how to get the accepted solution in the linked question working with spring boot.

Comment: Add it as an `initializer` .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to [M Deinum's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2696260/m-deinum) comment I found a solution:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // this would be used if run via java -jar service.war
        // SpringApplication app = new SpringApplication(Application.class);
        // CustomApplicationContextInitializer initializer = new CustomApplicationContextInitializer();
        // app.addInitializers(initializer);
        // app.run(args);
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder builder) {
        // this will be used within an app container
        CustomApplicationContextInitializer initializer = new CustomApplicationContextInitializer();
        return builder.initializers(initializer).sources(Application.class);
    }
}
```

Note the `builder.initializers(initializer)` part.