# Java EE Wildfly retrieve EntityManager from JNDI without persistence.xml

Tags: jpa, jakarta-ee, jndi, entitymanager, wildfly-10

I have recently moved to Java EE (Wildfly) and I'd like to lookup an `EntityManager` from JNDI. At present I am defining a datasource in my standalone.xml and successfully retrieving this via JNDI but this provides me with only the Datasource and not an Entity Manager.

I am aware that I can create a persistence.xml and use `@PersistenceContext` but I am really looking at a way to avoid compile time knowledge of the JNDI name, so instead want to perform a lookup based on runtime information to retrieve the appropriate Entity Manager.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately a persistence unit, from which an entity manager is derived can not be defined in a portable way without using a `persistence.xml` file.

If this is important for you please consider voting for [JPA_SPEC-114](https://java.net/jira/browse/JPA_SPEC-114) and additionally providing a comment there.

You can, more or less, make the persistence unit independent of the final JNDI name by using a [resource-ref](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2887967/what-is-resource-ref-in-web-xml-used-for). A resource-ref does causes your code to become dependent on a container specific mechanism to switch what the `resource-ref` is pointing to.

An alternative, with its own cons unfortunately, is using a [switchable data source](http://jdevelopment.nl/switching-data-sources-datasourcedefinition) approach. You can then define a data source using a fixed JNDI name and reference that from a `persistence.xml` file, and then use whatever method your switchable data source uses internally to go to the actual data source. This can then be either directly a data source implementation (such as shown in the link) or perhaps fetching another data source from JNDI (which effectively does what resource-ref does, but then using your own mechanism to switch)

Comment: Thanks, that is what my research and attempts led me to believe I was just hoping someone had some wizardry way around it :) - I might be able to make use of resource-ref to allow for some indirection.