# When creating a web app with JDBC, is the resource-ref even required?

Tags: java, tomcat, jdbc, jndi

I've been creating java web applications for many years.  I'm starting a new project and I thought I'd revisit some processes.  I'm using Java 8 and Tomcat 7.

I typically define a JNDI resource entry and pull this out as a DataSource.  I define the entry by creating a resource in my context, e.g.:

```
<Context>
  <Resource name="jdbc/db" .../>
</Context>
```

This entry contains everything I think I would need including name, driver, and config.  Yet all instructions I've seen for setting this up also says you need a resource-ref in your web.xml, like this:

```
<resource-ref>
  <res-ref-name>jdbc/db</res-ref-name>
  ...
</resource-ref>
```

See here:

- https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/jndi-datasource-examples-howto.html
- https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/jndi-resources-howto.html

Or any of the other 100s of tutorials you can find online.

However, I accidentally forgot to put in the resource-ref, and yet everything still worked fine (in tomcat).  Looking at things, it seems redundant.  Then I found this:

- [What is resource-ref in web.xml used for?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2887967/what-is-resource-ref-in-web-xml-used-for)

But the accepted (and popular) answer didn't seem to really answer the question to me.  It said the resource-ref was an abstraction but didn't explain how that abstraction is used.  Also, part of the example given was specifically for jboss (the `jndi-name`) and wouldn't even work in tomcat.

So what am I missing?  Is the resource-ref required?  Maybe not for tomcat but for other containers?  If it is an abstraction, how does that work?

Thanks!

Comment: What part of the accepted answer don't you understand? It already mentions it is not required, but it allows you to map a global JNDI resource name to an application specific resource name.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel: Where does it say it isn't required? The answer talks about abstractions, but only abstractions for specific containers and not even how to use them.

Comment: The very first sentence does: _"You can always refer to resources in your application directly by their JNDI name as configured in the container, but if you do so, essentially you are wiring the container-specific name into your code."_ It then explains the possibility to remap by defining a `resource-ref`.