# resource-ref element in web.xml

Tags: tomcat, datasource

I have read a couple of resources to get the answer for this question. But I am not getting convincing answer.

Question is : 
1)What is the use of resource-ref in web.xml ?
I am trying to link this specifically in tomcat container.

As per [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2887967/what-is-resource-ref-in-web-xml-used-for)

It will be one kind of indirection. Use application specific name in "web.xml" and container specific JNDI name exists in container specific file.

However in case of tomcat , how are we mapping resource name in web.xml to resource defined in context.xml  ? The reference documentation for tomcat also is not helping why to define resource-ref ? 
Same name in resource-ref as in context.xml. We are not achieving anything here

[Tomcat reference documentation](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/jndi-datasource-examples-howto.html) is also not helping much

In fact I have created sample Spring application in which I defined datasource in context.xml and referenced in Spring context file.
I have not defined anything in web.xml.

Comment: Are you asking "what good is `resource-ref`?" or are you asking "how do I make `resource-ref` work?"